# Add arrays into session array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add array (data from url) into a session array:

```
$nbA = array(); $nbE = array(); $nbS = array();  $nbAll = array();
for ($a = 1; $a <= $_GET['nbAdultes']; $a++) { $nbA[] .= "ADULTE"; }
for ($e = 1; $e <= $_GET['nbEnfants']; $e++) { $nbE[] .= "ENFANT"; }
for ($s = 1; $s <= $_GET['nbSeniors']; $s++) { $nbS[] .= "SENIOR"; }
$nbAll = array_merge($nbA, $nbE, $nbS);
$nbAllSession = array_merge($nbAll, $nbAll);
$_SESSION['nbAllSession'] = $nbAllSession;
print_r($nbAllSession);
print_r($nbAll);
```

Session array keep showing only 2 **arrays**.

It should look like this :

```
1. Array ( [0] => ADULTE [1] => ENFANT [2] => ENFANT ) 

2. Array ( [0] => ADULTE [1] => ADULTE [2] => ENFANT )
```

Final session array :

```
Array ( [0] => ADULTE [1] => ENFANT [2] => ENFANT [3] => ADULTE [4] => ADULTE [5] => ENFANT)
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['nbAllSession'][] = $nbAllSession;` change like this and checck

Comment: Same thing ....

Comment: and why this ? `$nbAllSession = array_merge($nbAll, $nbAll);`

Comment: To concatenate **nbAll** arrays : `Array ( [0] => ADULTE [1] => ENFANT [2] => ENFANT )` into one **$_SESSION['nbAllSession']** : `Array ( [0] => ADULTE [1] => ENFANT [2] => ENFANT [3] => ADULTE [4] => ADULTE [5] => ENFANT) `

Answer (score 0):

```
$cnt = 1;

$_GET['nbAdultes'] = $cnt;
$_GET['nbEnfants'] = $cnt;
$_GET['nbSeniors'] = $cnt;

$nbA = array(); 
$nbE = array(); 
$nbS = array();  
$nbAll = array();


for ($a = 1; $a <= $_GET['nbAdultes']; $a++) { $nbA[] = "ADULTE"; }
for ($e = 1; $e <= $_GET['nbEnfants']; $e++) { $nbE[] = "ENFANT"; }
for ($s = 1; $s <= $_GET['nbSeniors']; $s++) { $nbS[] = "SENIOR"; }


$nbAll = array_merge($nbA, $nbE, $nbS);


$nbAllSession = array_merge($nbAll, $nbAll);


$_SESSION['nbAllSession'] = $nbAllSession;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($nbAllSession);
print_r($nbAll);


//$nbA[] .= "ADULTE"; is not ok because $nbA[] is not **STRING**.
```

Comment: you need to give an example of the correct code. Otherwise someone will come along and do it for you and poach any recognition.

Comment: I wrote already, to not concatenate arrays like strings with "." just remove the dot `for ($a = 1; $a <= $_GET['nbAdultes']; $a++) { $nbA[] = "ADULTE"; }`

Comment: The problem is here : `$nbAllSession = array_merge($nbAll, $nbAll);`